# Mobile Vision APIs Barcode как сделать так, чтобы при обнаружении штрих-кода автоматически передавал значение штрих-кода?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Здравствуйте. Изучаю Mobile Vision APIs Barcode. И нигде не могу найти как сделать так, чтобы при обнаружении штрих-кода автоматически передавал значение штрих-кода? Чтобы не нажимать ни на какие кнопки. а автоматически при обнаружении. Есть ли такая функция. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В [примере гугла](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/BarcodeGraphicTracker.java#L71) в классе `BarcodeGraphicTracker` есть метод `onUpdate()`. Этот метод вызывается при обнаружении баркода. Соответственно вы можетете выполнять нужные вам действия из него:

```
/**
 * Update the position/characteristics of the item within the overlay.
 */
@Override
public void onUpdate(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detectionResults, Barcode item) {
    mOverlay.add(mGraphic);
    mGraphic.updateItem(item);

    // Do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все просто, когда создаете `CameraSource`, в билдер передается `BarcodeDetector`, так вот ему можно предварительно задать собственный процессор кодов. В метод `receiveDetections` процессора будут приходить "пойманные" камерой коды.

Код на Котлин.

```
val barcodeDetector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build()
barcodeDetector.setProcessor(object : Detector.Processor<Barcode> {
        override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detector.Detections<Barcode>) {
            // вот здесь и перебираете массив detections.detectedItems
        }
})
```